# How to add controls dynamic in xaml apps for windows 8

Tags: c#, xaml, grid

I am making a grid application, and in ItemsDetaiPage.xaml

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="App6.ItemDetailPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
IsTabStop="false"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App6"
xmlns:data="using:App6.Data"
xmlns:common="using:App6.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>

    <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroups[0].Items, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid
    Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}"
    DataContext="{Binding Group}"
    d:DataContext="{Binding AllGroups[0], Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>

    <!--
        The remainder of the page is one large FlipView that displays details for
        one item at a time, allowing the user to flip through all items in the chosen
        group
    -->
    <FlipView
        x:Name="flipView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,-3,0,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <!--
                    UserControl chosen as the templated item because it supports visual state management
                    Loaded/unloaded events explicitly subscribe to view state updates from the page
                -->
                <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">

                        <!-- Content is allowed to flow across as many columns as needed -->
                        <Grid Margin="120,0,20,20">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="800"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Date}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <WebView x:Name="webView" Width="800" Height="500"/>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="spButton" Orientation="Horizontal">

                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="4">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Tag}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state inside the FlipView -->
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                                <!-- Respect the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextColumns" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="97,0,87,57"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="400"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <!-- When snapped, the content is reformatted and scrolls vertically -->
                                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextColumns" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="17,0,17,57"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="scrollViewer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="richTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="280"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="160"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

            <!-- The back button respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <!-- The back button and title have different styles when snapped -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

My apps synthesis clips, each items is a game, each games have views, in StackPanel spButton I want to add buttons as a link to play videos. How can add dynamic buttons in file .cs

Comment: If i understood right, you want to bind Button content to WebView browsed pages, right?

Comment: yes, that right. Click that button, Webview display link of button content. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is typical case of invoking controls method through `View Model`.

To accomplish this, You need to following steps
1. Define an interface `INavigatable` that expose `Navigate` event
2. Implement the interface in `ViewModel`.
3. In the View Code behind, check if DataContext implements INavigatable interface.
4. If step 3 is true, Subscribe to `View Model` event in view code behind.

Example.

Step 1:

```
class NavigateEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public string Target {get;set;}
}

public delegate void NavigateEventHandler (object sender, NavigateEventArgs nargs);

public interface INavigatable
{
    event NavigateEventHandler Navigate;
}
```

Step 2:

```
class MyViewModel : INavigatable
{
    public event NavigateEventHandler Navigate;

    MyViewModel()
    {
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => 
        {
            RaiseNavigateEvent();
        }) ;
    }

    void RaiseNavigateEvent()
    {
        var temp = Navigate;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(new NavigateEventArgs{Target = Link});
        }
    }

    public string Link {get;set;} // this should be bound to Button.Content (preferably in XAML)
    public ICommand NavigateCommand{ get;set;}
}
```

Step 3/4:

```
public class MyView : Window
{
    public MyView()
    {
        ...
        Load += (s,e)=> 
        {
            if (this.DataContext is INavigatable)
            {
                ((INavigatable)(this.DataContext)).Navigate += (s1,e1) => webView.Navigate(e1.Target);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As an improvement, subscribe/unsubscribe the Navigate event in `DataContextChanged` event instead of `Load` event